# Why we normalize mutual information by square root of entropy?

Tags: normalization, mutual-information

Usually NMI(P,T) is expressed as $\frac{MI(P,T)}{\sqrt{H(P)H(T)}}$.

However, I don't know the reason why $\sqrt{H(P)H(T)}$ is a maximum value for Mutual information. Is there any proof or explanation?

Comment: The bound is $I(X,Y)\leq \min(H(X),H(Y))$; [several normalizations are used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information#Normalized_variants). Strel & Ghosh discuss your version as a matter of preference.  Strehl, A and Ghosh, J (2002), "Cluster Ensembles – A Knowledge Reuse Framework for Combining Multiple Partitions", The Journal of Machine Learning Research, 3 (Dec): 583–617  http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/strehl02a/strehl02a.pdf

Comment: You won't need to read the whole pdf; the relevant discussion that relates to your question is mostly on p589.